# Hardness proof?

Tags: aes, cbc

I am little curious about how do we calculate hardness proof of any cryptography algorithm?

Also where can I find hardness proof for AES and AES-CBC ?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

> I am little curious about how do we calculate hardness proof of any cryptography algorithm?

This is typically done by assuming some problem is hard (e.g., solving discrete log). Then proving that if someone can break the cryptography algorithm (e.g., diffie-hellman) that they can also break the hard problem. Once this relationship is established, we know that breaking the algorithm is at least as hard as breaking the hard problem.

> Also where can I find hardness proof for AES and AES-CBC?

Most symmetric algorithms (like AES) do not have a hardness proof in this sense. We just haven't come up with a good way to develop a symmetric cipher that can be based on the problems that are generally accepted as hard in such a way that the symmetric algorithm is still efficient enough for common use cases of symmetric algorithms (e.g., encrypting a whole lot of data that is being streamed over a network and has stringent requirements on latency).

Instead, what we get with most symmetric algorithms is the fact that really brilliant people who have broken other algorithms in the past are not able to break the proposed algorithm.

Comment: There are some limited proofs of things in the symmetric world though.  For instance, a celebrated result by Luby and Rackoff shows that if a small part of a Feistel network (i.e. DES) is secure, then the overall construction is secure.  So, we can say as long as the round function is secure then DES as a whole is secure.

Comment: @TravisMayberry very good comment. You could even add it as an answer.

Comment: We can also show that AES-CBC is secure as unauthenticated encryption if AES itself is a secure block cipher.